# Remove eventListener of element from the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

[image: screenshot form of inspect element on firefox]

This Image is from a live site that has a mouse enter and leave event. I've to remove its mouseLeave event to test some other things.

```
temp3.removeEventListener("mouseleave", this, true);
```

temp3 is a variable provided by firefox of that element *(use in console)*.
**This doesn't remove its mouseLeave event**

*Note: site is built on React Js*

*Edit:*
Yes, the question is duplicate but I don't think the previous one had solved the issue, that's why I'm asking again.

Comment: You can only remove an event listener if you still have the original callback.

Comment: You can only use `removeEventListener` is you still have a reference to the handler function. Without that, you can clone the element and replace it with its clone (this will remove *all* event handlers though)

Comment: Yes but I need its `mouseEnter` event too. that's why I couldn't clone it. `removeEventListener` isn't working, maybe it's a virtual DOM. I don't know

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry, It doesn't seem to work either. maybe we can't remove events without their original callback. hey, you should try that on this StackOverflow. pick any random event and try to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open chrome
2. Inspect the element
3. Click on the 'Event Listeners' tab

[image]